# accces to rest resource

Tags: apex, rest-api, webhooks

I created apex class with `@RestResource`. And `@HttpPost` method to use this code as Resource as the webhook URL, but the class is not invoking, please help here

CLASS:

```java
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Razorpay/*')
global class WebhooK_for_RazorPay 
{
    
    @HttpPost
    global static void ResponseFromPaymentLInk()
    {
        
        
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        system.debug('The request '+  request );
        RestResponse response = RestContext.response;
        system.debug('The response '+  response );
        
    }
     
}
```

Webhook URL:

```
https://techforceservices18-dev-ed.develop.my.site.com/services/apexrest/Razorpay
```

used in Razorpay

Comment: N.B. for a no-code solution for webhook processing in SFDC, checkout [Streamscript](https://www.streamscript.com/flow-webhooks)

Answer (score 1):

You should add the permission to the apex class and every other resource needed (i.e. Object Permission, Field-Level Security) to the Guest User.
To open the Guest User profile start from Setup, search for "Sites and" and click on "Sites", then on your site's name and on Public Access Settings button.
In the profile page you should click on *Enabled Apex Class Access* then on Edit button, add the needed classes and click Save.

Instead of modify the profile, you could create a Permission Set and add it to the Guest User (From the profile page there is a View users button). I think this would be a better approach due to the [end of life of permissions on profiles](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2023/permissions-updates-learn-moar-spring-23), moreover permission sets can be added to managed and unmanaged package.

Comment: i  have given the access to the profile ,but it is not access the apex code

Comment: @Mahesh What happens if you try to call that endpoint via Postman? Could you please post the error message?

Comment: NO ERROR while Interacting from the Postman.

Comment: @Mahesh Do you call `https://techforceservices18-dev-ed.develop.my.site.com/services/apexrest/Razorpay` without authentication header? Keep in mind that if you authenticate yourself, you are not testing the endpoint as a guest user.

Comment: ok. Understood . I Will test again

Comment: {
        "errorCode": "FORBIDDEN",
        "message": "You do not have access to the Apex class named: WebhooK_for_RazorPay"
    }      But, I given the access  to the Guest user profile  and class is  with Sharing Context.    @RubenDG

Comment: @Mahesh the error is clear, the guest user doesn't have access to that class. Do you have multiple sites/communities on that org? If so, be sure to grant the permission to the right user.

Answer (score 0):

I gave access to the "Guest User" profile for the class

[image]